# NSWindowController keyUp method plays sound

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, nswindowcontroller

I would like to be able to use the tableview in my NSWindowController using only keys. The up and down keys already work so all I need is the enter key for selecting. I do this using the keyUp method in my NSWindowController:

```
- (void)keyUp:(NSEvent *)the Event {
    if (theEvent.keyCode == 36) // Enter key
         // Do stuff
}
```

It works fine, the only problem is that whenever I press enter the computer plays a system sound. Does anyone know how I could mute the sound, or maybe another way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call `[super keyUp:theEvent];` as default

Comment: I added that but the sound is still playing. Is there a certain place it needs to be added?

Comment: be sure to do the same with keyDown methods

Comment: Okay so I just realized that the sound still plays even when I don't override keyUp. So the problem must have something to do with my window and not the event. Do you have any idea what might be the problem?

Comment: The view must allow accepting the first responder, and you have to do the [super keyUp:event]; in every superview.

Answer (score 2):

Okay so here's what I did to silence the sound for anyone who wants to know. Create a custom class for your view and override this method:

```
- (BOOL)performKeyEquivalent:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    [super performKeyEquivalent:theEvent];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Or you could add an event handler method with NSEvent.addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask([.KeyUpMask], handler:onKeyUp)  and then return nil in onKeyUp method, the reason you get the "funk-sound" is that when you forward the event it never ends anywhere unless its handled by such an event-handler as described above.